# How to check another div children by clicking on another div child in js

Tags: javascript

I need to select all boxes (option-1, option-2...) on click "select all" image in JS. I can select closest child but here child is in another div and the boxes, I need to select those in other div.
I have tried to `this.parentElemnet.children` but it's not working.
how to achieve this?

this is my code

CSS

```
      .box {
            background:red;
            padding:10px;
            width:200px;
            display:none;
        }

        .toggle-check-group {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.switch input {
    opacity: 0 !important;
    width: 0 !important;
    height: 0 !important;
}

.slider {
    cursor: url('../img/pest_cursor.svg'), move !important;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: .1s;
    transition: .1s;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: .8rem;
    margin-right: 10px;
    transition: top .1s;
}

    .slider:hover {
        top: -5px;
    }


input:checked + .slider {
    color: #188a80;
    background-color: #daf1ef;
    border: 1px solid #188a80;
}

input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

.slider::selection {
    color: none;
    background: none;
}
/* For Mozilla Firefox */
.slider::-moz-selection {
    color: none;
    background: none;
}

/* For Mozilla Firefox */
.slider::-webkit-selection {
    color: none;
    background: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="card">
        <div class="card-header " id="Div1">

            <h5 class="mb-0 ">
                <a class="btn-link " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#cp2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapsecroptwo">Select All
                                                                    <img src="select_all.png" class="check-all " onclick="CheckUnCheckAllselect(this,'pestname','UL_peststate','UL_peststate','',this.className)" />
                </a>
            </h5>
        </div>


        <div id="Div2" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingcroptwo" data-parent="#accordion" style="">
            <div class="card-body">

                <div id="Div3" class="category-list list-style-none">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div class="toggle-check-group">

                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll()"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-1</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-2</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-3</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll(); "><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-4</span></label>
                            </div>

                        </li>

                         <li>
                            <div class="toggle-check-group">

                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll()"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-1</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-2</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-3</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll(); "><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-4</span></label>
                            </div>

                        </li>

                         <li>
                            <div class="toggle-check-group">

                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll()"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-1</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-2</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-3</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll(); "><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-4</span></label>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
function CheckUnCheckAllselect() {
         var x=  this.parentElement.childrens.inputs.check ="true"
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're trying to do is check all your input elements after clicking the image.

If so, here is one way that you can select all checkboxes and mark them as checked by clicking the image, and also de-select them by clicking the same image.

Run the code snippet below:

```js
//get all elements with class name "myinput"
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("myinput");

//create toggle function
function Toggle() {
  //iterate over all checkboxes and mark check = true
  for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].type === 'checkbox')
      checkboxes[i].checked = !checkboxes[i].checked;
  }
}

function CheckUnCheckAllselect() {
  var x = this.parentElement.childrens.inputs.check = "true"
}
```

```css
.box {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  display: none;
}

.toggle-check-group {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0 !important;
  width: 0 !important;
  height: 0 !important;
}

.slider {
  cursor: url('../img/pest_cursor.svg'), move !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: .1s;
  transition: .1s;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #707070;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: .8rem;
  margin-right: 10px;
  transition: top .1s;
}

.slider:hover {
  top: -5px;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  color: #188a80;
  background-color: #daf1ef;
  border: 1px solid #188a80;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

.slider::selection {
  color: none;
  background: none;
}


/* For Mozilla Firefox */

.slider::-moz-selection {
  color: none;
  background: none;
}


/* For Mozilla Firefox */

.slider::-webkit-selection {
  color: none;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header " id="Div1">

    <h5 class="mb-0 ">
      <a class="btn-link " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#cp2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapsecroptwo">Select All
                                                                    <img style="width:40px;" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/31/17/55/check-mark-2025986__340.png" class="check-all " onclick="Toggle()" />
                </a>
    </h5>
  </div>


  <div id="Div2" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingcroptwo" data-parent="#accordion" style="">
    <div class="card-body">

      <div id="Div3" class="category-list list-style-none">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="toggle-check-group">

              <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll()"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-1</span></label>
              <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-2</span></label>
              <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-3</span></label>
              <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll(); "><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-4</span></label>
            </div>

          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="toggle-check-group">

              <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll()"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-1</span></label>
              <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-2</span></label>
              <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-3</span></label>
              <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll(); "><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-4</span></label>
            </div>

          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="toggle-check-group">

              <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll()"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-1</span></label>
              <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-2</span></label>
              <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-3</span></label>
              <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll(); "><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-4</span></label>
            </div>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ Dr. Tenma can we chnage this line of code
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); due to this it's selecting all other inputs on the page, Can we create it section specific

Comment: @ Dr. Tenma  like if we use "var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("myinput");" but can we select all myinput classes that coming in it's card

Comment: Hi, yes you can do it by class name as well. I've done so by changing it to `var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".myinput");` I've updated in the example code above. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @atul245 per your request, I've updated the code above to use `var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("myinput")` - If this helps solve your problem, please remember to mark correct and upvote :)